# Sending array using curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to send data from server 1 to server 2, first I select necessary data from the database, but how to send data with curl? I understand that I cannot send `$result` parameter just like in my code, but how should I do this?

My Code server 1:

```
public function setDivisions(){
        $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT *FROM data_divisions");
        $ch = curl_init('https://example.com/api.php?siteid='.$this->site_key.'');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $result);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($response);
    }
```

Code on server 2:

```
 $array = $_POST['result'];
    //loop throw array and insert data into database
```

Comment: You could JSON encode it, convert to XML, or make everything an individual field. JSON is probably easiest. You will need to `fetch` on server 1 though. All data needs to be sent, cant have a result object sent.

Comment: So I just json_encode the $result and then send it with curl ?

Comment: Yes, fetch all records, `json_encode`, send, `json_decode`.

Comment: Thank I understand now that I need to fetch all rows and send them one by one but how to retrieve these data in server 2?

Comment: Well if you have _encoded_ an array into a JSON string, then you _decode_ the received JSON, to get the array again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this, so I get data from my server 1 fetch it , json_encode it and now I need to send this data to server 2, but how can server2 receive this data? $array = $_POST['result']; this will probably not work. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use it that way.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://upxxx.cod3fus1ontm.com/curl/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode((object)["records" => json_encode($result)]));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

on receipt, like this!

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$content = json_decode($json, true);
$records = json_decode($content['records'], true);
foreach($records as $record) {
    echo $record['id'] . " - " . $record['text'] . "<br/>";
}
```

**remember, that as you did to encode, you will have to do to decode**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, file_get_contents("php://input"); what is this part and what should I insert in this place - > php://input ?

Comment: Somehow this not work, as it returns -> "array(5) { ["current_field"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["type"]=> NULL }

Answer (score 0):

Come on, **php://input** returns all raw data after the request's HTTP headers, regardless of content type.
When we do this with **file_get_contents** (which reads the contents of a file and puts it into a variable of type string), we can read the content that was sent by curl.
Reviewing the code, you can optimize as follows, when sending to the server you placed, I suggested:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode((object)["records" => json_encode($result)]));
```

you can replace it with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($result));
```

it's much simpler, but it's very important to put the query result inside a **json_encode**

finally, you can access the entire **body** of the message, through **file_get_contents ("php://input")** and put it inside a variable, which is nothing more than a JSON of the your query.
for you to understand how the parameters were passed, it is interesting to do the following:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php: // input");
var_dump($json); <- Here you see the thing as it is.
$records = json_decode($json, true); <- Here you generate an object with the content of json
var_dump($records);
```

With that, I think that solves the situation.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution, but as I mentioned before I get an empty string. In this case I get `string(19) bool(false) NULL ` .

Answer (score 0):

on server 1

```
$result = "result=".base64_encode($result)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $result);
...
```

on server 2

```
$array = base64_decode($_POST['result']);
```